# a question about the notation in the book "Opera de Cribro"

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

When I study the book "**Opera De Cribro**" by John Friedlander, Henryk Iwaniec-(2010), in Sections 1.2 and 1.3, I confused with notation used there. In page 3 it is defined:

$$\cal{A} = (a_n) , n\le x$$,

$$A(x)=\sum_{n\le x} a_n$$

$$\cal{A}_d=(am) , m \equiv 0 (\mod d)$$

and
$$A_d(x) =\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\ n\equiv 0 (\mod d)}} a_n$$

Now my question happens in the example 1.1 on page 5.

what are $a_n$ here? I wonder if $a_n=1$ or $a_n=n$?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is $a_n = 1$ for $n \in (x-y,x]$, $a_n  = 0$ otherwise, and $A_d$ is based on $b_n = 1$ for $n \in (x-y,x], d | n$, $b_n = 0$ otherwise

Comment: Crossposted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317332/a-question-about-the-notation-in-the-book-opera-de-cribro